# Raspberry B+ Power Supply calculation

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm new to Raspberry Pi and I don't understand about electricity. I bought a Raspberry B+ today and a 5V 3A power supply, but I'm afraid to connect it because in several places I read about using 5V 2A power supplies. I believe that only higher voltages can damage the Pi but, since I don't know about Amp, I don't know if this is true for 3A too.

My ideia is create a mini-personal server in my home, running Pidora. For data, I have a 1 Tb external USB drive with no external power supply (Seagate model SRD00F1).

My questions are:

- can I use the 5V 3A power supply on Raspberry Pi B+ without damage it?
- this power supply is compatible with my external USB drive to keep it on safely?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Raspberry Pi FAQ](http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) says that the B+ uses between 0.7 and 1.0 amps, and suggest a 1.2 amp power supply as a minimum.

Using a power supply with a higher amperage rating will **not** harm your Raspberry Pi. Devices only draw as much current (amperage) as they need. Any additional capacity is unused.

This is where your question about the external hard drive comes in. If you see in the FAQ, they suggest that you might want a larger power supply if you use all of the USB ports. Every USB device you plug in is going to draw more current. To figure out how much you need, you just add up the requirements of all of the devices like so:

```
Raspberry Pi = 0.7-1.0A
Mouse/Keyboard = 0.5A
Hard Drive = 1.0A
========================
TOTAL = 2.5A
```

**(These numbers are all fake... be sure to check the requirements for your actual devices.)**
So if your devices total 2.5A then a 3A supply will handle all of these plus some room for expansion. If all of your devices total 3.5A, maybe you need to consider a bigger one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. In an initial state I'll use keyboard/mouse for configuration. In the final state it will only have the external HD attached to the USB ports, so I believe it's ok.

Comment: I read (Wikipedia) that USB 3.0 uses 0,9A. I'm not sure if this applies to the entire external HD, but since probably won't use more than 1.8A, will have 1,2A enough to Raspberry in the final state.

Comment: USB 3.0 can **supply** up to 0.9A. Once again, it all depends on what you connect to it. If you connect a device that requires only 0.5A, that's all it's going to draw.